# Find a latest table daily on big query and concatenate with main table having same schema

Tags: google-bigquery

Daily I’m receiving a new table with same format name but different dates, I want to concatenate daily new table data with main_table.

I want to concatenate daily new table data with my main table.
Note : Dataset is same, schema also same

Answer (score 0):

Main Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourdataset.main_table`
(
  id INT,
  name STRING,
  inserted_date DATE
)
PARTITION BY inserted_date;
```

Main table is partitioned by DATE column. You can append data to main table and data from each new table will be stored in different date partitions.

```
INSERT INTO `yourdataset.main_table` VALUES (1, "name1", "2022-12-01");
INSERT INTO `yourdataset.main_table` VALUES (2, "name2", "2022-12-02");
INSERT INTO `yourdataset.main_table` VALUES (3, "name3", "2022-12-03");
INSERT INTO `yourdataset.main_table` VALUES (4, "name4", "2022-12-04");
```

Refer [BigQuery partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a query like this :

```sql
INSERT INTO `mydataset.main_table`
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `mydataset.daily_table_*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

In my example, I assume that you receive your daily table with a name like `daily_table_{currentstrdate}` `{currentstrdate}` has this format in my example `YYYYMMDD`

The schema is the same and you can apply an `insert/select` query.

In this example, I retrieved the `current date` dynamically and transformed it to `String`, if it's not mandatory for you, you can directly pass the daily table name.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was recieving the daily table with below example dates format. Data inside the table loading from last 14 days starts from yesterday's (20221121_20221204) and table creation date was today. 
Example : dailytable_20221121_20221204_20221205_041703

How can I write query with these date formats for daily newly added table?  I want to conctanate these data into my main_table.